# Ubuntu 9.10 VM loses connectivity during downloads

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I created an Ubuntu VM VMWare Workstation on my Win7 machine and was able to install several packages and download Eclipse without issue.  However, now I am attempting a repo sync for the android source code and a download from firefox of Motodev Studio without any success.  The downloads for each begin fine but reach a point where they hang.  It does not hang in the same spot every time, but it happens within a few minutes each time.  Anyone see anything like this before?  Ironically, I previously  had no problems with these same operations a few days ago on VMWare player for an Ubuntu VM image I picked up from vmware.net.  I have a wired connection and am not losing connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved by changing the Network Adapter setting from NAT to Bridged.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a "ping google.com" for several minutes, then hitting ^C and looking at the percentage of packet loss. That will tell you if there is a packet-dropping problem, but will not go very far in fixing it...

Comment: Not losing any packets:

874 transmitted, 874 received

Comment: OK, it must only be when the network is congested. You may be able to reduce the timeout on connections, which will hopefully un-hang it after the timeout value specified. I would also recommend setting the retry to about 3 or 5, if possible. However, bear in mind that the sync tool might not even have these options, or they may be buried.